# c++/MFC, Upgrading from Crystal Reports 11 to 13

Tags: c++, com, mfc, crystal-reports

I am trying to upgrade my code from using Crystal Reports 11 to Crystal Reports 13, but I am having troubles since I can't find the `craxdrt.dll` on the new Crystal Reports 13 package.

I used to import `craxdrt.dll` then instantiate it as a COM component

```
#import "craxdrt.dll"

IApplicationPtr         m_pCrystalEngine;
m_pCrystalEngine.CreateInstance("CrystalRuntime.Application.11");
```

Any idea how can I upgrade my code ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RDC was deprecated in CR9 and stopped shipping as of CR XI R2 (11.5), which itself is out of support already.

A walkaround is to write a COM or C++/CLI interop layer based on the .Net version of Crystal Report.